# Compare date and time columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I have a table that contains 2 columns date and time, both are character Varying, I am trying to return those only which are greater than the current date and time

| Date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 17-07-2022 | 05:00 |
| 17-07-2022 | 06:00 |
| 17-07-2022 | 10:00 |
| 17-07-2022 | 17:00 |
| 17-07-2022 | 18:00 |
| 18-07-2022 | 17:00 |

### Expected Output

If current time is : 12:00 AM

| Date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 17-07-2022 | 17:00 |
| 17-07-2022 | 18:00 |
| 18-07-2022 | 17:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below mentioned query:

```
select * from tab where concat(date_, ' ', time_)::timestamp <current_timestamp;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb40add3ea33b644ac2a0a5a5fb5bfae)